# How to change value of input from another input in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two grids of text boxes as shown here:
[Input Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXcZg.png)

The goal is that the user would fill out the above boxes and then as they fill out the below boxes, the above boxes auto update. ie if you entered 100 in the first box on the top and then 75 in the first box at the bottom, the first box would change to 25.

I tried to use onchange() but was unsuccessful. v-model seems to cause some problems with its two way binding, which makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML that populates the input boxes:

```
> <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTask">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th v-for="(column, columnIndex) in columns" :key="columnIndex">{{column}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(record, rowIndex) in records" :key="rowIndex">
          <td>{{record.row}}</td>
          <td v-for="(detail, index) in record.details" :key="index">
              <input type="text" v-model="detail.value">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
        <th v-for="(columnS, columnIndexS) in columns_Spend" :key="columnIndexS">{{columnS}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(recordS, rowIndexS) in records_Spend" :key="rowIndexS">
          <td>{{recordS.rowS}}</td>
          <td v-for="(detailS, indexS) in recordS.details_Spend" :key="indexS">
              <input type="text" v-model="detailS.value_Spend">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <button v-if="this.isEdit == false" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3">
      Submit
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, split up the `<td>` nodes into child components, and emit their value on input change to the parent (main) component. Then use a method to calculate and set the remaining value for the "other" box child component (saved presumably inside an Array, you need to find the right element inside that Array in that method). The changed array will automatically update the other child component, as it is bound to the prop.